# Design pattern for werewolf(social deduction) game

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I am trying to develop a social deduction game like [Werewolf (Mafia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werewolf_(social_deduction_game)).

In the game there are characters which have usable and passive abilities. During the night a player can pick 1 usable ability and choose 0 or more targets. At the end of the night, all abilities happen at the same time, and the next day the results of the abilities are effective.

The usable abilities include: killing someone, preventing someone from using an ability that night, preventing any abilities from being used on someone.

The passive abilities can be immunity to any of the types of usable abilities.

**I am looking for a software design pattern / architecture which prevents interdependence between the different abilities.**

I'm sorry for the (maybe) generic question, but I've been trying to get my head around this for quite a while.

Comment: What solutions have you considered so far, and why aren't you satisfied? Also, could you expand what you mean by "prevents interdependence"? Your question, as it is, is off-topic because it cannot be answered (too generic).

Comment: @MicheleDorigatti Sorry about that, I am having a hard time making this question more specific. I'll to edit the question. What I mean by interdependence is that changing one ability causes another ability to break.

Comment: Why wouldn't be enough to have a class for each ability and they all have the same interface or base class?

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting question and also very generic as you have mentioned. As I understand, the game of Mafia has players, each player has an assigned role, each role has one or more abilities (typically 1). There is no need to have dependency between the abilities. We can model the scenario of a player using his ability to negate or supersede the ability of some other player in two ways:

1) Ordering the execution of abilities correctly. For example, a player with role mafia can use ability to kill a particular player and let's say we mark that player as pending to be killed. But then during the same night if a player with role doctor saves the same player, we can unmark the player to be killed, thus negating the effect of killing ability by invoking the doctor's ability of saving "later" than the mafia's ability of killing.

2) If we do not want to execute the abilities in a proper sequence or we have a scenario where sequencing can't be done, then we can also do something like this. In one night, the set of abilities are finite, there can be multiple instances of the same ability (for example having 3 players designated as doctors) but even in this scenario, total instances of the ability (in this case "saving" ability) is finite. Now the Ability class can have a public method to render itself suspended. If for example a player with some special role which has the power and wants to prevent the ability of mafia to kill that night, it can invoke that ability of his by calling a method on the central GameController class that he wants to execute this ability of his. The GameController can then invoke the suspend method on the finite instances of killing abilities that are present in the game.

Thus in both the above ways of modeling the abilities and executing them, there is no dependency between the abilities. Basically the idea is that an ability that wants to get executed, registers itself with the central GameController independently of other abilities. GameController controls the execution and computes the final game state at the end of each night.

At the start of each night, the new instances of each ability can be created. If there are abilities that live across nights, then they can be modeled that way. But in any case, there must be a finite instances of abilities.

Some of the entities in this design are Player, Role, Ability, GameController, GameState.

Hope this helps!